# JSR-303 bean validation with Spring and iBatis

Tags: spring, ibatis, bean-validation, mybatis

Is it possible with JSR-303 bean validation to write a custom annotation that can talk to a back end service?

We accomplished this type of validation with the "old school" Spring validators. In that case, the validator was a Spring bean and could have other services injected into it. Then that validator is injected into the controller.

An example might be an annotation (perhaps @EmailExists) to verify if an email already exists. I can only do this with a SQL query using one of our services. I would prefer to "validate" this alongside the other annotations and check it as soon as possible and not have to explicity do it in a back end service.

NOTE: We are using iBatis/MyBatis so I can't use any JPA/Hibernate tricks :-)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely possible. Spring provides [dependency injection support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-overview) also within constraint validators. So you can simply inject any required services in your custom validators like this:

```
public class EmailExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailExists, String> {

    @Inject
    private EmailValidationService service;

    @Override
    public void initialize(EmailExists constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return service.exists(value);
    }
}
```

Depending on your concrete scenario it might be a good idea to first check "cheap" constraints such as `@NotNull` and only if these constraints are valid check more expensive constraints such as `@EmailExists`.

You can do this with help of [group sequences](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e971) and a redefined [default group sequence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-default-group-class)  for your type.

Comment: I didn't think about @Inject. We'll try that. Thanks so much!